# Google Earth Engine python error on initialize: googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I have installed Google Earth Engine Python client library according to instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install#install-options). I have tried both approaches, using pip and conda. On either case, I am able to install the package, and `import ee`. But when I run `ee.Initialize()` I get the following error:

`googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: earthengine  version: v1alpha`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Eventually ended up downgrading `google-api-python-client` from `2.0.2` to `1.12.8` and it worked. Looks like the latest release has this bug (they [just released](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/#history) it, 2 days ago)

Answer (score 0):

reticulate::py_install and 'google-api-python-client==1.12.8' is very useful

Comment: Maybe you should add some explanation to your answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tip.

I had the same issue and did this :

```
pip install google-api-python-client==1.12.8
```

afterwards my script worked perfectly!